# A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am new to React Native and I've installed firebase auth using npm like:
`npm  add @react-native-firebase/auth` and herein there's no such directory as C:\Users\Arpita Jha\Desktop\expert\test\node_modules@react-native-firebase\auth\android\build.gradle. 
and now I am facing this problem:

````
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Arpita Jha\Desktop\expert\test\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\android\build.gradle' line: 60

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'.
> Project with path ':@react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-firebase_auth'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 17s```
````

Comment: try with npm install @react-native-firebase/auth

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It's `npm install package_name` or  `yarn add package_name` for future reference

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
Uninstalled modules installed with npm and then reinstalled using yarn. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app
```